# Error: fractional component exceeds decimals in eithersJS

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethers.js

Why does the following return a fractional component error for exceeding decimals? It only seems to trigger on low balance.

If my balance is 0.1 ether or BNB I don't see an error but if my balance is 0.0001 I would see this error

*Error: fractional component exceeds decimals*

```js
var account = accounts[0]
var yourBalance = await provider.getBalance(account)
var fixedBalance= ethers.FixedNumber.fromValue(yourbalance , 18);
var stakedAmount = (fixedBalance * 0.50).toString();
var finalOutput = ethers.utils.parseUnits(stakedAmount , 18);  //this returns Error: fractional component exceeds decimals
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `toFixed(n)`

`var stakedAmount = (fixedBalance * 0.50).toFixed(6) ;`

`n` is defined as the maximum amount of precision you need in your decimal places.

I picked 6 arbitrarily but [this comment](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/648#issuecomment-1048447017) suggests you could potentially go up to 18?

`toFixed(n)` will also convert your number to a string so you can remove`toString()`.

I think it's because your floating point number has too many decimal places to be represented by `BigNumber` thus, you need to truncate the precision of your decimal places.

For posterity and people coming here via search engines, the full traceback I received was:

```
Error: fractional component exceeds decimals
 (fault="underflow", operation="parseFixed", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)
```

It's very interesting because I literally had a similar error just now. A couple of hours after you.

[This issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/648), [this issue](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2098) and this [code snippet](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/a71f51825571d1ea0fa997c1352d5b4d85643416/packages/bignumber/src.ts/fixednumber.ts#L102-L105) helped me figure it out.

Comment: Worth nothing that `toFixed` *may* round the number up too.

Answer (score 1):

If USDT supports `6 decimals` and my input is `153.60000000000002` (more than 6 dec. places), it will cause overflow/underflow errors.

The problem with @tomiwa's `toFixed` solution is that it rounds the number. I don't want that.

This is how I solved it:

```js
// if USDT supports 6 decimals 
// and my input is 153.60000000000002 (more than 6 dec. places)
// it will cause overflow/underflow errors.
// this function trims too long decimals. 
function trim_decimal_overflow(n, decimals){
    n+=""

    if(n.indexOf(".") === -1) return n
    
    const arr = n.split(".");
    const fraction = arr[1] .substr(0, decimals);
    return arr[0] + "." + fraction;
}
```